# How can I forcefully change the padding inside a mat-expansion-panel-body?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, frontend

so I just created an expansion panel and it's working fine (it's very hardcoded though). I need to, however, eliminate a padding entirely from the subpanel part and I can't find a proper way to do it.

Here's the panel:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLoKn.png

You can notice that there is a white border that I want to eliminate (upon inspection, in the div.mat-expansion-panel-body part, there is a padding. When I set it to 0, it fixes and the white borders vanish. I tried however the following in my .css:

```
div.mat-expansion-panel-body {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

But it didn't work. If anyone's got a solution to fix that I'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, late to the party, but the way I did it was setting margin to negative for the parent element, like `mat-expansion-panel {margin-left: -1.5em;}` This will cancel out the positive margin from the generated div within. Not the cleanest, but I do not like setting ::ng-deep everywhere.

Answer (score 8):

Add the styles to your `styles.css` which is the global style, but this will affect all of the mat-expansions throughout your application.

```html
div.mat-expansion-panel-body {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

The reason it's not working when you add it into the style of your components *vs* adding it in the global `styles.css` is that the styles are encapsulated and the `mat-expansion-body` is created outside the style of that component.

If you want to avoid that style appearing on every mat-expansion-panel-body you can create a class for example `remove-mat-expansion-padding` and give it to the mat-expansion-panel like this:

```
<mat-expansion-panel class="remove-mat-expansion-panel-padding">
```

And then in your `styles.css`

```css
.remove-mat-expansion-panel-padding .mat-expansion-panel-content .mat-expansion-panel-body{
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

So that the styles only apply on those `mat-expansion-panel` in which you add the class `remove-mat-expansion-panel-padding` instead of all the expansion panels throughout the app

Comment: This is the best response that I've seen which explains how to deal with CSS formatting for angular material components that are specific to a user-created component.  Thank you!!!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Detailed information with the pros and cons of a couple of possible solutions is provided, and a clear and working example is also added. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You might try the next approach(using SCSS):

```
::ng-deep {
    mat-expansion-panel {
        .mat-expansion-panel-body {
            padding: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `mat-expansion-panel-body` is created internaly by Material.

Such as another Material components, to apply changes (mainly styles) to these components is very hard.

The alternative to solve this problem is remove the emulated encapsulation from your component, setting to `ViewEncapsulation.None`. But, with that, the styles applied into your component (css selectors, like classes, tags, ids, etc) are available for all components of your application.

To prevent encapsulation styles problems into your application, is a good idea apply an `#id` to your component container (in this case, the `mat-expansion-panel`), and work your component style inside this `#id` CSS selector, like the example:

```html
<mat-expansion-panel id="my-component-name-style-container">
   <!-- your content -->
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

```css
#my-component-name-style-container mat-expansion-panel-body {
   padding: 0;
}
```

The idea of apply a CSS `#id` selector with the component name is prevent that other components have the same style (more or less "encapsulated" into the `#component-name` style selector, which is available for all application components because the encapsulation is `none`).

I hope I've helped